# Newbie - Trying to update a database record from within a JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Hopefully this just needs a two-minute answer from some kind soul.

The PHP webpage displays the contents of a database record. That works fine. The database opens, and a record is displayed correctly for a given $refno.

A feature I'm trying to add is to update that record (replacing whatever's in the status field with an "X"), by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Z.

I've found some JQuery for listening for Ctrl+Shift+Z key combinations, and that also works. But what doesn't work is the update!

The code (below) includes an alert (for testing purposes only).

If I omit the line with the UPDATE, then the alert fires, so I can tell I'm reaching that script.
If I include the line with the UPDATE then the alert doesn't fire and the record is not updated.

What's my mistake?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//CTRL+Shift+z combo
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if( e.which === 90 && e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey ){
    alert('Whhooppie!'); 
        UPDATE TestTable SET status='X' WHERE refno='$refno';
    }
}); 
</script>
```

Very many thanks for picking this up. Not suceeded yet - I really am a newbie and have been struggling for the last few hours trying to make sense of it all. And failed.

You've certainly got the idea of what I'm wanting to do (updating the status to "X" on a record for a given $refno) and I'm confident your coding is in the right direction. But I need to localize your code with my database, table and field names, and there are a few things I don't understand.

In your first bit of code, I'm guessing I don't need the lines about clicking a button, since this is being triggered by the Ctrl+Shift+Z. So I've only replaced my incorrect UPDATE line with your &.ajax section. I'm also guessing "tacos" is just an example, but I could be wrong. (As mentioned, all new stuff for me.)

So my code is now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//CTRL+Shift+z combo
$(document).keydown(function(e){
if( e.which === 90 && e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey ){
$.ajax({
url: "my_php_page.php",
     data: {id:1,value:"&refno"},
     method: "post"
  })
  .done(function(data) {
     alert(data); 
  });
}
}); 
</script>
```

For my_php_page.php:
I've replaced "test" with the actual database name (shown below as xxx), 
put the database password between the quote marks (shown below as yyy), 
replaced "my_table" with the actual table name,
and changed "value = ? where table_id = ?" as follows:

```
<?php
// print_r($_POST); 

$dsn  = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx';   
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'yyy'; 

$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

$id      = isset($_POST['id'])    ? $_POST['id']    : ''; 
$value   = isset($_POST['value']) ? $_POST['value'] : '';  

$success = false; 

if (!empty($id) && !empty($value)) {

$query = "update TestTable set status='X' where refno='$value'";

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$success = $stmt->execute(array($value,$id));
}

if ($success) echo "it worked!";
     else echo "it did not work...!";; 

?>
```

(Do I need the double ;; on final line?)

When pressing Ctrl+Shift+Z I get neither "it worked!" nor "it did not work...!", and the record is not updated.

I'm sure I must be getting close, but where am I going wrong.

Again, many thanks for your help.

Comment: you need to use ajax to talk to a php page and pass it the info you need to perform the update. the php, which can do server side stuff, will contain your update statement.

Comment: Just including a SQL query in the middle of your Javascript will simply cause a syntax error. There are many reasons why this won't work, not the least of which is that your Javascript is running in a different environment from your database server, possibly on a different machine. You need to make a call to your server (with AJAX, pehaps) and handle that with some server-side code to update your database.

Comment: Also, do not create a PHP script that will execute arbitrary SQL commands, else someone could submit a malicious SQL command to the script.

Comment: use prepared queries.  i provided an example below.  you need the question marks in the query instead of `$variables`.  use `$stmt->execute(array($value,$id));` to bind values to those question marks.

Comment: and i'm not trying to be mean... but if you have to ask if you need `;;` in your code, you're probably not ready to fully understand most of the topics you're asking about.  you should start with a good PDO tutorial.  and then a good ajax tutorial. and then something on the difference between client and server side scripting.

Comment: I updated my post.  There's a little more error handling in there.  Make sure your PHP runs by itself before you try to call it from the javascript.  Test with constant values in your query instead of grabbing post values.  If that works, then call it with ajax.  The PDO link I gave talks about error handling.

Answer (score 0):

you tagged it with jquery, so i used jquery...

read this page:  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

and this: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

**and this:  http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom**

```
<button id="do_stuff">do stuff!</button>

<script>
   $("#do_stuff").on('click',function(){

      $.ajax({
         url: "my_php_page.php",
         data: {id:1,value:"tacos"},
         method: "post"
      })
      .done(function(data) {
         alert(data); 
      });
   }); 
</script>
```

and then inside of `my_php_page.php`

```
<?php

// print_r($_POST); 

$dsn  = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test';   
$user = 'root';
$pass = ''; 

$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

$id      = isset($_POST['id'])    ? $_POST['id']    : ''; 
$value   = isset($_POST['value']) ? $_POST['value'] : '';  

if (!empty($id) && !empty($value)) {

   $query = "update my_table set value = ? where table_id = ? "; 
   $stmt  = $db->prepare($query);

   // run the query and bind the values 
   $success = $stmt->execute(array($value,$id));

   if ($success) echo "it worked!";
            // else echo "it did not work...!"; 
            else echo $stmt->errorInfo()[2];
}
else echo "post params were blank"; 

?>
```

this is fully functional with a table schema like...

```
create table my_table (
    table_id   int, 
    value      varchar(20)
 );

 insert into my_table values (1,'one');
```

Comment: Almost there!
Thank you so much for the responses. This was my first time to ask on StackOverflow and I'm bowled over with the speed and quality of the replies.
I am, however, still struggling with this. Almost there but need guidance to finish.
I've editted my original with a follow-up question and would be grateful for any help.

Comment: You're right, I'm way out of my depth with this, but under time constraints to finish the job. I'll try again with your advice and if unsuccessful I'll resort to updating the records directly via myphp.
Sorry to have taken up your time and many thanks again for your help.